# In Aglio is it possible to run server from Node.js library?

Tags: node.js, apiblueprint, aglio

When you are working with binary - you have such option:

```
aglio -i input.apib -s
```

But what if I need to do the same from js library? I checked the code and it looks for me that there is no such possibility, but maybe I'm wrong. I can invoke binary from the js code, but it looks like overkill for me.
Aglio version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I didn't found any way to use functionality similar to `aglio -s` from js library. The approach I chosen is to use it in normal way as parsing and saving output data to html, but after that I'm opening this html and subscribing to any changes related to the docs, which I compiled.

In result it gives me pretty similar behaviour like `aglio -s` provides.

Answer (score 1):

`aglio` has a javascript API you can use from your application.
It's stated in the appropriate [README section](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio#nodejs-library)

Comment: Are you sure you read my question properly? I know that it has js library, I'm not asking to show me it.